# mysqlでテーブル間の情報参照の上、リンクを表示する

Tags: php, mysql

会員制掲示板をphp+mysqlで作ってます。

ユーザーごとに投稿が表示されるのですが、 自分の投稿以外は「投稿編集」「投稿削除」できないようにしたいです。 （※「投稿編集」「投稿削除」のリンクを表示させない）

例：testuserでログインしたらtestuser以外のユーザーの投稿は 「投稿編集」「投稿削除」のリンクを表示させない

【posts】テーブルのuser_idは【users】テーブルのidの値が入るようになってます。 その値同士が同じであれば「投稿編集」「投稿削除」のリンクを表示するという構成です。

実装はしたものの、正常に動作しません。 どこが間違っているのかご教示願います。

テーブル情報はこんな感じ。 
【users】テーブル

```
create table users (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  name varchar(255),
  email varchar(255),
  created_at datetime,
  password varchar(255)
);
```

【posts】テーブル

```
create table posts (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  user_id int,
  name varchar(255),
  title varchar(255),
  content text,
  created_at datetime,
  updated_at datetime
);
```

サンプルコードは以下です。

```
<?php

session_start();


require_once('config.php');
require_once('functions.php');

if (empty($_SESSION['id'])) {
  header('Location: login.php');
  exit;
}
//var_dump($_SESSION['id']);
//var_dump($_SESSION['name']);

$dbh = connectDatabase();
$sql = "select * from posts";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$posts = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//var_dump($posts);

$dbh = connectDatabase();
$sql = "select * from users";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>ELITES Blog</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="on"><a href="index.php">ホーム</a></li>
    <li class="on"><a href="list.php">日記一覧</a></li>
    <li class="on"><a href="add.php">日記追加</a></li>
    <li class="on"><a href="logout.php">ログアウト</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<h1>ELITES Blog</h1>
<h2>ELITES 公式開発ブログ</h2>
<h3>投稿されたブログ一覧</h3>
<?php if (count($posts)) : ?>
  <?php foreach($posts as $post) : ?>
  <ul>
    <li class="link"><a href="detail.php?id=<?php echo h($post['id'])?>"><?php echo h($post['title'])?>（作成日：<?php echo h($post['updated_at'])?>）</a>
      <?php if (h($users['id']) == h($post['user_id'])) : ?>
      ｜[<a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo h($post['id'])?>">編集</a>]｜[<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo h($post['id'])?>">削除</a>]
      <?php endif ?>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <?php endforeach ?>
<?php else : ?>
  投稿された日記はありません。
<?php endif ?>

<footer>
  <p><a href="http://nowall.co.jp">株式会社 NOWALL</a></p>
  <small>2015 NOWALL,Inc. All Right Reserved.</small>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

以下のソースから、ログインしているユーザが、投稿しているユーザと一致していれば編集などが可能になるようですので、

```
<?php if (h($users['id']) == h($post['user_id'])) : ?>
```

一方、usersは、

```
$sql = "select * from users";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

と、usersテーブルの中身を全取得しています。

usersのidと、postのuser_idを比較するのではなく、
現在ログインしているユーザid($_SESSION['id'])と、postのuser_idを比較するのではないでしょうか。

以上です。

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
$dbh = connectDatabase();
$sql = "select * from users";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
*/
```

↑　不要

```
<?php if (h($users['id']) == h($post['user_id'])) : ?>
      ｜[<a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo h($post['id'])?>">編集</a>]｜[<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo h($post['id'])?>">削除</a>]
<?php endif ?>
```

↓　変更

```
<?php if (h($_SESSION['id']) == h($post['user_id'])) : ?>
      ｜[<a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo h($post['id'])?>">編集</a>]｜[<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo h($post['id'])?>">削除</a>]
<?php endif ?>
```

$users['id']
　　↓
$_SESSION['id']